# Google Cloud Platform: Temporary Server error?

Tags: joomla, google-cloud-platform, cdn, google-cloud-networking

Google Cloud Platform is raising an error like:
`Error: Server Error The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.`

We have GCP, CDN and Google Cloud Load Balancing with GCP.

How can we fix this server error?

Comment: FWIW, the error is rather a generic one and sometimes can be misleading as the root cause might not actually be a transient condition. But you'll need to provide a lot more info to clarify the context. GCP is a whole family of products.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing instance type to backend instances to increase the request timeout. Frontend instances have a timeout of ~60 seconds. Here is a detailed list of errors in GCP [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors)

Answer (score 1):

There is a detailed [status message](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#what_is_logged) in the HTTP Load Balancer [logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#how_to_view_logs).

Also, I suggest that you confirm from [Developers Console](https://cloud.console.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/loadBalancers/list) that the corresponding backends are healthy.